# Autowiring fails in integration tests with JUnit and Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, integration-testing

i'm working with the following tutorial [Spring Data JPA Tutorial: Integration Testing](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-integration-testing/) and i get the following exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lp_grocery_list.ProductEntityTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: lp_grocery_list.db.repository.ProductsRepository lp_grocery_list.ProductEntityTest.repository; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [lp_grocery_list.db.repository.ProductsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

The test (src/test/java):

```
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PersistenceContext.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ProductEntityTest {

@Autowired
ProductsRepository repository;

@Test
public void findAllProducts() {
    List<ProductsEntity> peList = repository.findAll();
    assertTrue("Found not the expected products", peList.size() == 15);
}
```

The PersistenceContext (src/test/java):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:applicationTestContext.xml" })
public class PersistenceContext {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {

    BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

The applicationTestContext.xml contains the following line (and more, but i don't think that is important here...):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="lp_grocery_list" />
```

The ProductsRepository (src/main/java):

```
@Repository
public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductsEntity, Long>{

List<ProductsEntity> findByProductName(String productName);
}
```

Any hints or ideas ? I hope i didn't forget anything.

**Edit**

With the proposed change from `@ContextConfiguration` to `@ImportResource` i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Bean name 'dataSource' is already used in this <beans> element
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.checkNameUniqueness(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:313)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
```

** Second edit **

I found the solution, i defined two times the `dataSource` that caused the exception.

Comment: Do you have the `jpa:repositories` configuration element? (Or whatever it is.)

Comment: Does `applicationTestContext.xml` reside in src/test/resources?

Comment: Yes the jpa:repositories base-package is defined and the `applicationTestContext.xml`is in the src/test/resources folder

Comment: Is `ProductsRepository` in the 'lp_grocery_list' package?

Comment: `ProductsRepository` is in the subpackage lp_grocery_list.repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:applicationTestContext.xml" })
```

should be

```
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:applicationTestContext.xml" })
```

`@ContextConfiguration` should be used in the test class, but `@Configuration` classes that load contexts from other sources use `@ImportResource`.

---

You also don't need `@Configuration` on your `ProductEntityTest` class.

Comment: With this solution i get the `Failed to load Application Context` exception

Comment: @smsnheck Can you post the full stack trace in and edit your question?

Comment: The stacktrace with the `@ImportResource` annotation?

Comment: @smsnheck The full stack trace of the exception you just got when you tried this.

Comment: @smsnheck Don't define two beans with the name `dataSource`.

Comment: Yep. I just read over that little information. Removing the double bean solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @SotiriosDelimanolis i got the same type for exception, but in my case `@Autowired private Environment env; ` id null, os it through the null pointer exception.

Answer (score -2):

This is no object of type `ProductsRepository` in the Spring's context. Although there is an interface `ProductsRepository` but obviously it cannot be instantiated by Spring. You can create a class that `implements` this interface and annotate that with the `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: Sub types of `JpaRepository`, if configured correctly, are proxied and created as beans. That is how `spring-jpa-data` works.

Comment: Actually you don't even need the `@Repository`. If an interface extends `CrudRepository` (or any of it's descendants) and is not annotated with `@NoRepositoryBean` a Spring Data repository will be created

Comment: But it is not the solution. Even without the `@Repository` annotation the test fails.